# Show only the current location marker using watchPosition

Tags: javascript, google-maps, mobile, gps, cordova

I'm trying to create a single marker on a google map to show the users current location. Using the following code I am able to do that but each time watchPosition refreshes it creates a new point. How do I clear out previous markers each time a new point is added?

```
// Geolocation
var win = function(position) {
    var iconimage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/current_location_small.png',
        new google.maps.Size(15, 15),
        new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        new google.maps.Point(7, 7)
    );
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var long = position.coords.longitude;
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        icon: iconimage
    });

    marker.setMap(map);
};

var watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(win);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could declare your marker outside of the function and use the `setPosition(LatLng)` method

```
// Geolocation
var marker=null;
var win = function(position) {

    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var long = position.coords.longitude;
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
    if(marker==null){
         var iconimage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/current_location_small.png',
             new google.maps.Size(15, 15),
             new google.maps.Point(0,0),
             new google.maps.Point(7, 7)
         );
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            icon: iconimage
        });
        marker.setMap(map);
    }else{
        marker.setPosition(myLatlng);
    }
};

var watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(win);
```

Comment: Glad to help, for future reference `marker.setMap(null)` removes the marker from the map :)

Comment: @kevmc This answer doesn't make sense as the code you have put does not make use of marker.serMap(null)

Answer (score 1):

or as stated in the comments setnull and this then redraws.
of course the screen flickers and it redraws at the rate the gps updates
remove the if line in my code below and you would constantly draw a trail

```
var watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {

  // Get current position
  pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);

  // Redefine current location marker
  if (typeof(marker) != "undefined") marker.setMap(null);
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: pos,
     map: map,
     title: 'you are here',
     icon : user
  },watchOptions);

 }); //end constant watchPosition
```